# Open and read file from Google Drive in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api, rubygems

I am using the Google drive API which provides me with "export links" which seem to redirect for a download of the document.

The result provides this:

```
{"text/csv":"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1w6oq05R8piP4N4A-xxxxxxxx-rI&exportFormat=csv",
"application/pdf":"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1w6oq05R8piP4N4A-xxxxxxxx-rI&exportFormat=pdf",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1w6oq05R8piP4N4A-xxxxxxxx-rI&exportFormat=xlsx"}
```

I am using [Yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu) but when I try to read one of these files I get a result that indicates that "the content has moved", so a redirect of sorts.

How can I open one of these URLs so they can be read by Yomu, or do you know of any alternate ways of using the Google Drive API to achieve the desired data?

Answer (score 4):

I am able to load that file using curl, and it seems to work fine. BTW, you will want to mask the `id` in the PDF and XLSX URLs if you want to keep the document private. Also, the CSV will be easier to use than the XLSX file.

Try in your shell

```
curl "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1w6oq05R8piP4N4A-xxxx-rI&exportFormat=csv"
```

Try in an IRB/rails console session:

```
`curl "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1w6oq05R8piP4N4A-xxxx-rI&exportFormat=csv"`

require 'open-uri'
open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1w6oq05R8piP4N4A-xxxx-rI&exportFormat=csv').read

require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'
CSV.parse(open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1w6oq05R8piP4N4A-xxxx-rI&exportFormat=csv'))
```

If you really want to use the full XLSX:

```
require 'yomu'
Yomu.new('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=1w6oq05R8piP4N4A-xxxx-rI&exportFormat=xlsx').text
```

But the result looks incredibly difficult to parse.

Comment: Just used this to get access to a Google Doc in 2022 using Ruby. Thanks so much!

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the first several docs I was trying to use had some sort of permissions issue or some criteria specific to them which was causing the "moved" notice. I tried on some other files and I got success using Yomu the way I wanted to.